# How to manually authenticate users in laravel passport, using tokens

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-websockets

Am using a custom handler for websocket in laravel

web.php

```
WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('/app/{appKey}', \App\SocketServer\SocketHandler::class);
```

This router dose not accept middleware, thats why am trying to send the token from the frontend and get the user by token

SocketHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\SocketServer;
class SocketHandler extends WebSocketHandler
{
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {

            parent::onOpen($connection);
            $guzzleRequest = $connection->httpRequest;
            parse_str($guzzleRequest->getUri()->getQuery(), $getParameters);

            $token = $getParameters['token'] ?? null;
            if (!$token) {
                throw new Exception('Token required', 401);
            }

            // Here am trying to get the user by the token
           $user = //
           Auth::login($user)
    }

 
}
```

How to authenticate a user inside the SockerHandler class?

thank you

Comment: Did you try `auth()->guard('api')->setUser($user);`

Comment: @PsyLogic, this is not the question, i want to get the user by the token, that i get from the client

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve TokenRepository and get the token

```php
use Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository;
 
$tokenRepository = app(TokenRepository::class);

// this will return instance of \Laravel\Passport\Token
$token = $tokenRepository->find($token); 

if($token){
  $user = $token->user; //User model instance
}

// .....
```

More details functions:

- [\Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/src/TokenRepository.php)
- [\Laravel\Passport\Token](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/src/Token.php)

Comment: I tryed this, but didn't work. 
This (find) function seems it's trying to find a recored in 'token' table where the id  = token. 

But the token that stored in the table are short, and the one that i get from API is much longer, i think there should be another layer of handling the long token before passing it to the find() function